# Looking for the formal name of a request response pattern implemented in aspnet core or http modules in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns

There is a recognizable pattern in many servers that implement a generic request/response processor. Among many examples, I can name aspnet core middleware or  http modules in IIS.

With the request/response pattern that I am referring to, 3rd party developers can implement modules by implementing a well define interface (like middleware in aspnet core). The execution engine can be configured to hand a context (includes both request and response) to each of the modules in order until a response is ready to send back to the requestor.

The challenge that I have is that this specific pattern is not part of GOF patterns that everyone know about. I can tell it is a behavioral pattern.

Is there any formal name and definition for this pattern that is independent of any platform or programming language?